How to Change case of part of Filename with Powershell and Regex?
Have a bunch of Video files, that all contain either 1080P / 720P in the end of Base Filename but before the Extension usually, but we can assume all the filenames have either one of two anywhere in the Basename.
Now I wanna rename file such that only the case of that specific string changes, means only either 1080P becomes 1080p or 720P becomes 720p.
I already tried with this code, but it doesn't do a damn thing:
$validExts = '.mkv', '.mp4', '.mov', '.avi', '.wmv', '.webm', '.avchd', '.flv'
Get-ChildItem -File |
    Where-Object Extension -In $validExts |
    Where-Object Length -Gt 500mb |
    Rename-Item -NewName {
        ($_.BaseName -replace '^.*(1080P|720P)$', $_.Value.ToLower())
    }
### Also tried with ^.*(1080P|720P).*$, but doesn't work either
### Even if I put it like this `...{$_.Value.ToLower()}`, 
###  it only produces unexpected weird results like 
###  "ISLAND OF THE DOLLS 2023 ENGLISH 1080P.Value.ToLower()"

Example:
Input:
ISLAND OF THE DOLLS 2023 ENGLISH 1080P.mkv
Output:
ISLAND OF THE DOLLS 2023 ENGLISH 1080p.mkv

$_.Value is nothing without a scriptblock, did you mean that or is it just a typo in your question?

Oh I really hoped that $_.Value would be there to help me replace that part, so how do I fix that ? Oh wait a second, even if I add the curly braces around it, it just produces weird results rather than intended one, can you help me out on that ?

Seems like in your code you wanted to use replacement with a scriptblock but in this case is not really needed, what you can do instead is add an additional filter to get only those files that actually have the uppercase P, then you can use the automatic $Matches variable for the replacement:
$validExts = '.mkv', '.mp4', '.mov', '.avi', '.wmv', '.webm', '.avchd', '.flv'
Get-ChildItem -File |
    Where-Object Extension -In $validExts |
    Where-Object Length -GT 500mb |
    Where-Object Name -CMatch '(?:1080|720)P' | # if there is a match here it gets stored in `$Matches`
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace($Matches[0], $Matches[0].ToLower()) }


wouldn't $RegexMatch = '(1080|720)P';         Get-ChildItem -File | Where-Object {          $_.Extension -in $validExts -and          # $_.Length -GT 500mb -and         $_.Name -CMatch $RegexMatch     } | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace $RegexMatch, '$1p' } be a bit better?

Santiago's helpful answer shows a solution that is also backward-compatible with Windows PowerShell.
A PowerShell (Core) 7 solution based on your own attempt (note the enclosure of $_.Value.ToLower() in { ... }, a script block):
Get-ChildItem -File |
  Where-Object Extension -In $validExts |
  Where-Object Length -Gt 500mb |
  Rename-Item -NewName {
    ($_.BaseName -creplace '(?<=\b1080|\b720)P', { $_.Value.ToLower() }) + $_.Extension
  }


-creplace is the case-sensitive variant of -replace (the latter's alias is -ireplace).

Note that any input files whose name doesn't match the pattern are in effect left untouched.



This will apply Rename-Item to all files that meet the extension and length requirements, even if they do not contain 1080P or 720P.

@lit: Yes, but that is benign, as hinted at by the last bullet point in the answer. To spell it out: -replace returns the input string as-is if it doesn't match the regex,
and when Rename-Item -NewName sees the same name as the current one, it is in effect a no-op for a given file. Unfortunately, that's not how it works for directories; fixing that has been green-lit, but is yet to be implemented - see GitHub issue #14903
